# How can I use java decimalformat to change my double type number from x.0E-4 to 0.000x?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to use java decimalformat to change my double type number from x.0E-4 to 0.000x.
How can I do it please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended way to get a `NumberFormat` instance which may be a `DecimalFormat` (I assume depending on your locale which you can pass to the `getInstance`) and configuring it. If you would rather not use a pattern there are other methods you can use to configure the `DecimalFormat`. This pattern will convert the number to a string with up to 6 decimal places.

```
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    if (f instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        ((DecimalFormat) f).applyPattern("0.0#####");
    }  
    System.out.println(f.format(0.0004));
```